# Exporting Access Database into Text file through php

Tags: php, pdo, ms-access-2010

Scenario:

I am exporting a table Named "Registration" from access database and writing into a file named "isl.txt" in php using pdo. Fields separated by "," and Records separated by "\\"(i know it should be "\n" for convenience but it cant take a new line in text file. Don't know why !! so i have chosen "\\")

**Registration Table in Access:**

Roll_Num,Course,Marks,Discipline,Session

0,CS-101,89,CS,Fall94

0,CS-102,70,CS,Fall94

0,CS-103,59,CS,Fall94

**Code:**

```
$fl = fopen('isl.txt', 'w');
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=D:\Islamabad.mdb;Uid=;Pwd=;");
$results = $db->query("select * from `Registration`");

while ($row = $results->fetch()) {

foreach ($row as $value) {
   $lastv = end($row);

    if ($value != $lastv){

        fwrite($fl, $value.",");
        }

}
 fwrite($fl, $value."\\");
}
 fclose($fl);
```

**Output:**

0,0,CS-101,CS-101,89,89,CS,CS,Fall94\0,0,CS-102,CS-102,70,70,CS,CS,Fall94\0,0,CS-103,CS-103,59,59,CS,CS,Fall94

**Problem:**

As u see, every single value of record is repeating two times. Please Check whats wrong with my code!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repeating values are because you are not specifying a *`fetch_style`* in `$results->fetch([fetch_style])`. According to the manual - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php - when *`fetch_style`* is not specified, it defaults `to value of PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE (which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH)`.

> **PDO::FETCH_BOTH** (default): returns an array indexed by both column
>   name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

Try changing to -

```
while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

OR

```
while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
```